# Finding a generator of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb{Z})^*$

Tags: number-theory, group-theory, finite-groups

Is there a method for finding a [primitive element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) (generator) of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb{Z})^*$, where $p$ is a prime number?

Comment: you mean a primitive root of unity?

Comment: No i mean:
A group G which contains an element a with maximum order 
ord(a) = |G| is said to be cyclic. Elements with maximum order are called primitive elements or generators.

Comment: But you referred to Zp specifically. Why not 1?

Comment: What do you mean with "Why not 1?".

Comment: you mean Zp, the group of integers modulo p, under the operation of addition modulo p, right? 1 is a generator for that group.

Comment: No I mean Zp in respect of multiplication modulo p.

Comment: That is, the group of nonzero integers mod p, under multiplication mod p. Then you are asking for primitive roots of unity mod p!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n

Comment: The same link you have provided contains a detailed answer you are looking for, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots) @gosom

Comment: The references provided in that article should provide further methods. I've that Cohen's book is pretty good, for example.

Comment: Check out Section 4.8 (computing n-th primitive root of unity) in *Algorithms For Computer Algebra* by Keith O. Geddes, Stephen R. Czapor, George Labahn.

Comment: If $p$ is of the form $2^\alpha + 1$ then the primitive elements are precisely the quadratic non-residues

Answer (score 3):

William Stein has a [webpage](http://modular.math.washington.edu/edu/2007/spring/ent/ent-html/node31.html) on the problem of finding generators for $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$.

There are some [probabilistic polytime algorithms](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/34/52/73/PDF/polypr.pdf) for finding primitive roots. Also assuming the Extended Riemann Hypothesis, there [are polytime algorithms](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFMQFjAB&url=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.7636&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=szK8T5HpOuTH6AH20tkv&usg=AFQjCNHlRZEakEoq_i4QXj4Ven2C-EWoeQ).

However in general no efficient (fast) algorithm is known.